# Spotify Apps - How to log people out of Facebook

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

Logging people in with their Facebook accounts is quite easy with the Spotify API's auth methods. However, I couldn't find any procedure on the API docs for logging people out of Facebook.

Do I have to do this manually, utilizing the Facebook API, or does Spotify provide a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to log the user out in the Spotify Apps API. In order to do achieve it, you need to make a request to `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=<access_token>&next=<next>`

where:

- `access_token` is the same token you use to log a user in
- `next` is a URL that belongs to the same domain as the registered one on Facebook for your app

Comment: Well, this works, thanks. For future readers, I also needed to add next url in RequestedPermissions section of my manifest file.

Comment: In the `RequiredPermissions` attribute of your manifest you include a list of hosts, not complete URLs. Thus, for Facebook you would add `https://www.facebook.com`.